# Vertically align content in a bootstrap div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok, so I am mightly confused to what I guess should be simple.  Take the code below, just started using Bootstrap so probably not perfect but sufficient for an example.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <h1>Logo Text</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <ul> Navbar.... </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So imagining that code above is my header, how can I ensure that both sides for logo and navbar are centered horizontally and vertically in the their respective div's?

I suspect I need to use a table, table-cell, vertical-align: center but is that really efficient or right?

Need to remain responsive.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to center vertically, all you need is to setup your `padding: 10px 0;` and play around with that 10 until you get it lined up. It will help if you cascade a clearfix class to the col-md-8. Now, that is the short sweet and simple (SSS) answer. But you mentioned you are now using Bootstrap. If I were you, I would use the Bootstrap navbar and modify accordingly. The whole idea of using such a robust framework is to make sure you take advantage of all the bells and whistles that come with it with less coding time.

I built a sample [**here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWrVeJ)

Comment: This is fine and I set up the default navbar pretty much how you have done it, I just wanted to see how easy it would be to break that up a little and be a bit more custom.

Comment: Absolutely! Custom away! That's what you should be doing, but don't mess around too much with the classes that bootstrap has setup for you. They will make your life way easier.

Comment: Yes, I have set up a custom.css so I can override without destroying bootstrap.  I get what you mean now with display:inline-block below. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this class:

```
.vertical_align_middle {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    /* etc */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.vertical_align{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just thought about it for a minute.

If I set one of the inner divs to this

```
.inner {
  height: 100px;
  display: table;
```

}

Then on the actual content that I want to position

```
.pos {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
```

}

So I guess the important thing here is you need to set a height either by % or something more specific so that the alignment has something to work from.  And of course set the entire div to be a table with the content of the div a table-cell.

Is that the right way?

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap to finally break away from the old school and pesky table layouts, it will be contradictory to fall back into it by using display: table. Those CSS properties are used for very specific purposes. AS you learn more about Bootstrap, you'll see display:inline-block is your friend :)

Comment: yeah, totally agree, but a table fixes everything right :)  This is my issue though, when I search about for solutions I keep seeing people using tables, I guess I am not the only one to stop focussing on old ways!

Comment: You will be falling into bad habits again. The whole point on getting away from display tables is to not compromise responsiveness. Tables are the enemy. Remember that. Only use tables for tabular forms. That's it. Everything else is DIVs and responsive code. Avoid tables like the plague

Comment: Indeed, that was my issue when i used the table, it breaks the responsive structure which is totally counter productive.

Answer (score 1):

```
.col-md-8, .col-md-4 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; // Vertical
    justify-content: center; // Horizontal
}
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the askers question, you should always add an explanation as to how this solves the problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow, recommended reading [ask]